# JavaFX: Add item in parent-window-ComboBox when new item is added into child-window-ComboBox

Tags: javafx, combobox, binding

**Use-Case**

Parent-window contains menu-bar at top, that has one menu (e.g. Data), and that menu contains only one menu-item (e.g. Import). When user selects 'Import' menu-item, a dialog-window appears. There is also a comboBox in the parent-window.

Dialog-window has comboBox, textField and a button. Once user enter any text in textField and clicks the button, that text, say fruit-name, gets added into comboBox. There is another button to close the dialog (not important here).

I am trying to add new item in the parent-window's comboBox automatically when a new item is added into dialog-window's comboBox, but I am not able to get the desired result. I haven't found any comboBox property where binding can be of any help (not explored thoroughly).

I am new to JavaFX, so please help me out with right coding practices if you find any gaps in the code below (apart from the functionality that is not working).

**Main.java** (package: problem)

```
    package problem;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
            MainWindowController mwc = new MainWindowController();
            mwc.launchMainWindow(primaryStage);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.fxml** (package: problem)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

    <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="problem.MainWindowController">
       <children>
          <MenuBar>
            <menus>
              <Menu text="Data">
                <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="importMenuItem" onAction="#launchImportDialog" text="Import" />
                </items>
              </Menu>
            </menus>
          </MenuBar>
          <ComboBox fx:id="fruitsComboBox" prefWidth="150.0" />
       </children>
    </VBox>
```

**MainWindowController.java** (package: problem)

```
    package problem;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import problem.importdata.ImportDataController;

    public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {
        private Stage primaryStage;
        @FXML
        private MenuItem importMenuItem;
        @FXML
        private ComboBox fruitsComboBox;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        }

        public void launchMainWindow(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
            VBox root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Problem");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        @FXML
        private void launchImportDialog() throws IOException {
            new ImportDataController().launchImportDialog(primaryStage);
        }

        @FXML
        public void addFruitsComboBox(String fruit) {
            ObservableList<String> fruitsList = fruitsComboBox.getItems();
            fruitsList.add(fruit);
            fruitsComboBox.setItems(fruitsList);
        }
    }
```

**ImportData.fxml** (package: problem.importdata)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

    <VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="problem.importdata.ImportDataController">
       <children>
          <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
             <children>
                <ComboBox fx:id="fruitsComboBox" prefWidth="150.0" />
             </children>
          </HBox>
          <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
             <children>
                <TextField fx:id="fruitTextField" />
                <Button fx:id="addFruitButton" onAction="#onClickAddFruitBtn" text="Add Fruit" />
             </children>
          </HBox>
          <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
             <children>
                <Button fx:id="closeButton" onAction="#onClickCloseBtn" text="Close" />
             </children>
          </HBox>
       </children>
    </VBox>
```

**ImportDataController.java** (package: problem.importdata)

```
    package problem.importdata;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Modality;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import problem.MainWindowController;
    import problem.Main;

    public class ImportDataController {
        private Stage primaryStage;
        @FXML
        private ComboBox fruitsComboBox;
        @FXML
        private TextField fruitTextField;
        @FXML
        private Button addFruitButton;
        @FXML
        private Button closeButton;

        public void launchImportDialog(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("importdata/ImportData.fxml"));
            VBox root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            stage.setTitle("Import");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.showAndWait();
        }

        @FXML
        private void onClickCloseBtn() throws IOException {
            Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
        }

        @FXML
        private void onClickAddFruitBtn() throws IOException {
            String fruit = fruitTextField.getText();
            fruitsComboBox.getItems().add(fruit);
            fruitTextField.clear();

            // Trying to add fruit data in main windows combo box but it is not working
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
            VBox root = loader.load();
            MainWindowController mwc = loader.<MainWindowController>getController();
            mwc.addFruitsComboBox(fruit);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Trying to add fruit data in main windows combo box but it is not working
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
VBox root = loader.load();
MainWindowController mwc = loader.<MainWindowController>getController();
mwc.addFruitsComboBox(fruit);
```

It's not working because instead of accessing a controller that already exists, you're creating a new instance.

Sharing the data between the controllers can be done in multiple ways, in your case, I believe, it will be fine to simply pass the reference to the `ComboBox` item list to your `ImportDataController`, the same way you pass your `Stage` around.

```
new ImportDataController().launchImportDialog(primaryStage, fruitsComboBox.getItems());
```

It makes sense to do it the simple way, because the role of the controller in question is clearly defined - it imports the fruits, so it needs the data model to update.

If your controller was more complex this approach would be terrible for obvious reasons. You don't really want to maintain a long and messy list of parameters.

Comment: Thank you @Dth... as I am new to stackoverflow, my up-vote though registered will not be displayed publicly

Comment: This still won't work unless you fix another problem in `ImportDataController`: the `ImportDataController` you create with `new ImportDataController()` is not the controller for the UI you load from `ImportData.fxml` (because the `FXMLLoader` creates a new instance...). You need `loader.setController(this)` before `VBox root = loader.load()` and you then need to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from `ImportData.fxml`.

Comment: "If your controller [were] more complex...". The same approach would essentially work no matter how complex this is. The only difference is you would define a class ("model") encapsulating the data you needed to share, and pass a reference to that class (instead of passing a list). Great answer, btw.

Comment: @James_D, thank you very much... even after making changes suggested by Dth, I was still struggling with the null reference of private ObservableList even after copying the reference inside launchImportDialog function... now I got your point and the code is working as desired... thank you both again

Comment: @NimishJain You should mark the answer as correct (click the check mark).

Comment: Done.... one more thing @James_D, do I need to remove the fx:controller from all the fxml wherever I am calling any method by creating an instance of Controller class? how then Controls having fx:id works wherever set for any window?

Comment: @NimishJain You need to remove `fx:controller` if you are calling `setController(...)` on the `FXMLLoader`. The `fx:controller` attribute basically tells the `FXMLLoader` to create an instance of the specified class and use it as the controller. If you have already specified a controller with `setController(...)` you don't want the `FXMLLoader` to do that (and it will throw an exception if you try).